# Retrofit different domains using

Tags: android, retrofit, endpoint

I use the retrofit library for the Android network operation. I have two domain addresses. I store the addresses with SharedPreferences. How can I use different endpoints.

for example:

www.mehmet.com/api/list

ww.deniz.com/api/list

www......

www.....

Code:

```
public class ptsApi {

    public static String BASE_URL = "";
    private static ptsApi instance;
    private ptsService ptsService;

    private ptsApi(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =  c.getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String BASE_URL = sharedpreferences.getString("api","").toString();

        final Gson gson =
                new GsonBuilder().
                        setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                        .create();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        ptsService = retrofit.create(ptsService.class);
    }

    public static ptsApi getInstance(Context c) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ptsApi(c);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public Observable<SearchModel> getSearch(@NonNull String plate) {
        return ptsService.searchData(plate);
    }
```

Comment: The right way to do this is to create different service interfaces for different domains, and to maintain different retrofit client instances for each domain

Comment: Addresses are not fixed. The user will change the domain address.

Comment: so you want to base domain string to be dynamic, i.e change at run time? but the endpoints remain the same? (i.e the service interface) you'd probably have to use reflection to achieve this with retrofit, so that you can mutate the base domain address at run time

Comment: Yes the domain will change at runtime. The endpoints will remain the same. How do I use an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
public class ptsApi {
    enum TYPE {
        MEHMENT, DENIZ

    }

    private static ptsApi instance;
    private ptsService ptsService;

    private ptsApi(Context c, TYPE type) {
        final String BASE_URL = getEndpoint(type);

        final Gson gson =
                new GsonBuilder().
                        setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                        .create();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        ptsService = retrofit.create(ptsService.class);
    }

    public static ptsApi getInstance(Context c, TYPE type) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ptsApi(c, type);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public Observable<SearchModel> getSearch(@NonNull String plate) {
        return ptsService.searchData(plate);
    }

    public String getEndpoint(TYPE type) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = c.getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        switch (type) {
            case MEHMENT:
                return sharedpreferences.getString("mehmentApi","").toString();
            case DENIZ:
                return sharedpreferences.getString("denizApi","").toString();
            default:
                return "your default";
        }
    }
}
```

or you can create some method like

```
public static ptsApi getMehmetInstance(Context c) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ptsApi(c, MEHMENT);
    }
    return instance;
}
public static ptsApi getDenizInstance(Context c) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ptsApi(c, DENIZ);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I keep the address in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
public void getRetrofit(Sting baseDomain){
         Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseDomain)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
   return retorfit;
}
```

U can change domain and create a new retroift instance and use it accordingly for api calls

In your code u can pass domain along with context just like above.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? have a method that updates the `ptsService` instance upon changing the baseUrl

```
public class ptsApi {

    public static String BASE_URL = "";
    private static ptsApi instance;
    private ptsService ptsService;

    // a function you can call to change the base url
    // which in turn updates the ptsService instance
    // to start making calls to the new baseUrl.
    public void changeBaseUrl(String newBaseUrl) {
        BASE_URL = newBaseUrl;
        updatePtsService();
    }

    // Created this function to remove code duplication
    private void updatePtsService() {
        final Gson gson =
                new GsonBuilder().
                        setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                        .create();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        ptsService = retrofit.create(ptsService.class);
    }

    private ptsApi(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =  c.getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String BASE_URL = sharedpreferences.getString("api","").toString();
        // re-using this to remove code duplication.
        updatePtsService();
    }

    public static ptsApi getInstance(Context c) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ptsApi(c);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public Observable<SearchModel> getSearch(@NonNull String plate) {
        return ptsService.searchData(plate);
    }
}
```

Comment: It was not. Always use the first address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one Retrofit instance with okhttp interceptore that allows runtime changes to the URL hostname :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

/** An interceptor that allows runtime changes to the URL hostname. */
public final class HostSelectionInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  private volatile String host;

  public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
  }

  @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    String host = this.host;
    if (host != null) {
      HttpUrl newUrl = request.url().newBuilder()
          .host(host)
          .build();
      request = request.newBuilder()
          .url(newUrl)
          .build();
    }
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HostSelectionInterceptor interceptor = new HostSelectionInterceptor();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.coca-cola.com/robots.txt")
        .build();

    okhttp3.Call call1 = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
    okhttp3.Response response1 = call1.execute();
    System.out.println("RESPONSE FROM: " + response1.request().url());
    System.out.println(response1.body().string());

    interceptor.setHost("www.pepsi.com");

    okhttp3.Call call2 = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
    okhttp3.Response response2 = call2.execute();
    System.out.println("RESPONSE FROM: " + response2.request().url());
    System.out.println(response2.body().string());
  }
}
```

for more informations :

1. [https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1404#issuecomment-207408548)
2. https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1404#issuecomment-207408548